# Insertion is done twice on DB

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a single record in the dataset but from the method that saves to the database, it is executed twice. What can be caused this? how do I solve it? I save the file in a blob storage.

```
def saveFile[T](dataset: Dataset[T]): Unit = {
   dataset
   .write
   .mode("overwrite")
   .json("...json")
}

val res = df.map(x => {
       ...
       val operation = saveToTable()
       ...
    })

saveFile(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is being executed twice because `dataset.write.mode("overwrite").json("...json")` will save the dataset to the specified location and if you run the `saveFile` method again, it will save the dataset again to the specified location. Try using `dataset.write.mode("append").json("...json")` which will save the dataset to the specified location if it doesn't exist, otherwise it will append the dataset to the specified location.